# .first() element not working with dynamic generated <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, spring

I think I am missing some minor concept here, but have done enough googling to find that but no use. Hence posting on this forum seeking some help.

I am generating navigation tab dynamically using this code:

```
<div class="tabbable">  
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  id="testing">

   <li ng-repeat="storageOption in gridOptions[$index].ownedJay" class=""><a href="#c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}" >Data{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}</a></li>


   </ul >
```

In above code, class is left blank. Above code can create many li based on number of elements in storageOption (ng-repeat).

But I want to add class "active" in first li only.
For that I have added following code in the script section of same page:

```
$(".tabbable ul li").first().addClass("active");
```

But above code is adding active class in all the li generated.

Can anyone please let me know where I am missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to re-initialize the event for all after adding new componenets to perform your event for newly added

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jm1yf5tk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in angular way, as angular does provided that option by `ng-class` that basically need expression like `ng-class="{'class': expression}"`.In `ng-class` expression you could use `$first` that tells you its first element of `ng-repeat` or not, and use `ng-href` instead of `href`.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="storageOption in gridOptions[$index].ownedJay" ng-class="{'active': first}">
    <a ng-href="#c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}" >Data{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}</a>
</li>
```

**Alternative**

If you want to make active togglable then you could simply maintain one flag that will have the information of which `li` is selected.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="testing" ng-init="selected=0">
    <li ng-repeat="storageOption in gridOptions[$index].ownedJay" 
      ng-class="{'active': $index == $parent.selected}" 
      ng-click="$parent.selected == $index">
        <a ng-href="#c{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}" >
          Data{{storageOption.StorageHostname}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul >
```

In above markup I used `$index` but you could unique thing if you have it you `ng-repeat` array.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for your response.. It worked. Just a minor edit : ng-class="{'active': $first}" (in first example)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tabbable").find('li:nth-child(1)').addClass("active");
```

Try using a different selector to select the first li

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jm1yf5tk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class attribute to check if the $index is 0 then add class active.